# Xpath error - Need to find solution to use importxml formula to automate rates

Tags: google-sheets

importxml("https://www.google.com/travel/search?q=autocamp%20joshua%20tree&g2lb=2502548%2C2503771%2C2503781%2C4258168%2C4270442%2C4284970%2C4291517%2C4306835%2C4597339%2C4757164%2C4814050%2C4850738%2C4864715%2C4874190%2C4886480%2C4893075%2C4920132%2C4924070%2C4965990%2C4985712%2C4990494%2C72246918%2C72248281%2C72256471%2C72262103%2C72271034%2C72271797%2C72272556%2C72276044%2C72280386&hl=en-US&gl=us&ssta=1&ts=CAESABpJCikSJzIlMHg4MGRhZGJmYWY4MGQ4MWI3OjB4YWMzYzMxNjBlODFlY2I0ZRIcEhQKBwjnDxAGGA0SBwjnDxAGGA4YATIECAAQACoHCgU6A1VTRA&qs=CAEyKENob0l6cGI3d0k2c2pKNnNBUm9OTDJjdk1URndkMkl3TlhCbmRoQUI4AkILCU7LHuhgMTysGAFCCwlOyx7oYDE8rBgB&ap=KigKEgnxRZB2IxBBQBFr9PRMNhRdwBISCTUBcPZzE0FAEWv09IRZE13AMAC6AQdyZXZpZXdz&ictx=1","//*[@id='reviews']/c-wiz/c-wiz/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]")

Keeps returning "N/A"

Expecting to receive the actual review score. However, I keep getting "N/A". Hoping to use the response to streamline a lot of manual inputs.

Any common error advice also welcome!